# extract characters from a list of names and make it a numeric command

Tags: r, class, object, character, numeric

I have a list of objects: area$X1,area$X2,area$X3,area$X4, ...area$X100.The class of each object is numeric. These objects are extracted from the results of a SpatialPixelsDataFrame. I have calculated the buffer area for different animal tracks from 1 to 100.

Eg. area$X1 is 
0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0
I want to count the number of 1 in area$X1, so I used command

```
table<-table(area$X1)
0      1 
600097   1504 
#extract the number of 1s 
table[[2]]
```

which gives me 1504

this would give the number of 1s, and thus give me the size of the buffer area.

However, I want to do the same for all the other objects, area$X2 until area$X100. And calculate the mean number of 1s overall. I want to automate this process. How can I do it?

Currently, what I did is to create a list of names

```
names<-paste("area$X",1:100,sep="")
```

While I get the list of names I wanted, the class of elements in "names" is character.

```
names: "area$X1" "area$X2" "area$X3" "area$X4" "area$X5" "area$X6" "area$X7" 
..."area$X99"  "area$X100"
class(names[1]): "character"
```

"area$X1" is no longer the numeric I wanted. To add on, now if I try command :

```
 table(names[1])
     area$X1 
              1
```

it wont be a table of 0 and 1. It just contain one element, which is the name "area$X1".

I tried to removed quotation marks but it didn't help.

Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your area only has 0's or 1's, you can just use colSums to get the number of 1's

```
colSums(area)
mean_area <- mean(colSums(area))
```

If not, and you want to ensure you are only counting the number of values with 1's, you can set area == 1

```
colSums(area == 1)
```

You can also use apply to iterate the functions column-wise (or row-wise, see ?apply) for future reference if you have more complex calculations

```
apply(area, 2, function(x) sum(x == 1))
mean_area <- mean(apply(area, 2, function(x) sum(x == 1)))
```

For instance

```
area <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, 50), 5, 10))
colnames(area) <- paste0("X", 1:ncol(area))

area$X1 == 1 # gives TRUE, FALSE, which is equivalent to 1, 0 and can be summed to get the number of 1's
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
sum(area$X1)
# [1] 2
```

Comment: colSums did not work because area is in the class of SpaitalPiexelsDataFrame

Comment: any luck with the apply option?

Comment: Thanks. Apply function works. But is there a way to calculate the variance of area for each ID?

Comment: consider the single case `var(area$X1)`, use apply to iterate function column-wise `apply(area, 2, function(x) var(x))` or `apply(area, 2, var)` for short.

Comment: I want to calculate the Var between different track ID. Not within each track. To simplify my question, I am not sure how to store answer from each step in the loop into a list of numeric and calculate the variance of it. See my answer below for the loop I have.

Comment: Please provide a sample data frame, I need to see the structure of your data set.  I don't see where the ID's are, you have only described the tracts.  Look at the apply, lapply and sapply functions, I do not usually use loops in R when it can be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is very helpful. I eventually worked out the following code

```
for (i in 1:length(uniqueID)){
b<-apply(area[i],1,function(x) sum(x == 1))
c<-c+sum(b)
}
mean<-c/length(uniqueID)
```

Thanks a lot!
But is there a way to calculate the variance of area for each ID?